# X2go Start Server

Tags: x2go

I have installed X2go on my Ubuntu machine acting as a server.  But how do I start the service? When I try to connect to it from an x2go client machine, it just opens the remote desktop window and then instantly closes it. The documentation on x2go is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out Unity isn't compatible, nor is hardly any other desktop environments without workarounds. Installed XFCE4, and it worked fine.